# ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION -> sticky intent on all devices / os versions?

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver, sticky-broadcast

I tested that registering `ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION` `("android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE")` sends **sticky** `Intent`. Can we be sure that we receive this sticky Intent on all devices and os versions? And will it be available in the future release of android os?

Comment: If you mean using a broadcast receiver to receive this intent, no it won't work on android 8+ for apps using targetSdk >= 24

Comment: @Merka Any link to this?

Comment: it is explained here: https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/background-optimization.html

Comment: @Merka I was taking about STICKY Intent, not about registering receiver. Btw ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION still works on api 24 and higher. "Note: A BroadcastReceiver registered with Context.registerReceiver() continues to receive these broadcasts while the app is running."

Comment: I didn't understand your case and still I am not sure what it is. But if this explanation in above link doesn't affect your usecase and you don't need it to work when app is not in foreground, I think you won't have problem. Also I don't know if it will be available in future release of android or not and I don't think anyone can predict it :D

Comment: The author is asking if the intent is guaranteed to be sticky on future Android version. This is relevant because the documentation does not state that the intent is sticky.